# How to link to last comment on a node page?

Tags: comments

I have some nodes with lots of comments that use a pager. I want to link from the top of the node page to the last comment.

Is there a simpler way than building the link like this ([source](http://drupal.org/node/292126#comment-5040568)):

1. Get number of (published) comments for a certain node;
2. Get number of comments per page (it can differ from on content type to another);
3. 1+2 = number of pages;
4. Get cid of the last comment;
5. Create a link like /node/[nid]?page=[page]#comment-[cid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a simpler way than that, but you can combine two of those steps into one so you at least only need to make a single database call:

```
function node_last_comment_link($node, $link_text) {
  // Get the num active comments and most recent comment id
  $data = db_query('SELECT MAX(cid) AS cid, COUNT(cid) AS cnt FROM {comment} WHERE nid = :nid AND status = 1', array(':nid' => $node->nid))->fetchObject();

  // No comments, no link
  if ($data->cnt == 0) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Get the num comments per page
  $var_name = 'comment_default_per_page_' . $node->type;
  $sensible_default = 50;
  $num_per_page = variable_get($var_name, $sensible_default);
  $page_num = floor($data->cnt / $num_per_page);

  //Build and return a URL
  $query = array();

  // No point adding ?page=0
  if ($page_num > 0) {
    $query['page'] = $page_num;
  }

  $fragment = 'comment-' . $data->cid;
  return l($link_text, 'node/' . $node->nid, array('query' => $query, 'fragment' => $fragment));
}
```

I've given that a quick test and it seems to work but it might need a bit of massaging, especially if you have threading turned on :)

Comment: I ended up adding a 2nd pager to the top: http://drupal.org/node/141381#comment-4984614

Comment: @Clive, nice answer, thanks. But what if we have tree view in comments. E.g. we have 5 pages with comments and somebody replies on comment on the second page. CID will be the lastest but how can we detect `$page_num`? In this case we need to detect all comment parents maybe..

Comment: So I think better would be to use `comment_get_display_page()`

Comment: @milkovsky Yeah I think you're right :)