# Refer to comment node in CKEditor

Tags: 7, nodes, comments, wysiwyg

I would like to have a reference to a comment in my node detail.

For example when I create a node of content type = Proposal and someone comments with a good argument I would like to add the argument in my node body and add a reference to the comment that suggested the argument.

I have no clue on how to start with this, google didn't help me much either. Could this be possible to do?

Comment: Create a link like /node/[nid]?page=[page]#comment-[cid]? Taken from [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/27657/16495).

Comment: And perhaps also look at token support for ckeditor here: [Token Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_insert)